# How to call a number using skype api

Tags: php, html, skype

I have some phone numbers diplayed from database. When i click on that number i have to call that number using skype.I am using a php code. Can anyone help me how can call to skype by passing this number as a skype api parameter.

I am using this skype api.
Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service
It works. But it based on skype username. I need api based on mobile number.Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skype API (found here http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris) allows you to use links on a webpage to initiate calls.

From the documentation.

> In its simplest form, you can embed a hyperlink referencing a Skype
>   URI in a webpage to place a Skype call. For example, to initiate a
>   call to the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service, the link would be:

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service</a>
```

In the example above this will call the **echo123** contact. There are many more ways of handeling this request. I suggest reading the documentation above as it provides methods of directly calling numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works only if skype is installed in pc. I need a skype installation setup if pc does not contain skype.... please anyone help me